# Tkinter clock crashing with infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm creating a single `StringVar` called `time_display`, which contains a string of the fashion `3:14:02`, and a single label in the window which should (in theory) reflect updates to said `StringVar`. However, when I call `updateTime` to check the time and update it, I crash in an infinite loop. Other adjustments I have made have resulted in no infinite loop but no updating clock either. What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Clock")

def updateTime(var):
    hours = time.localtime().tm_hour
    if hours == 0:
        hours = 12
    minutes = time.localtime().tm_min
    if minutes < 10:
        minutes = '0' + str(minutes)
    else:
        minutes = str(minutes)
    seconds = time.localtime().tm_sec
    if seconds < 10:
        seconds = '0' + str(seconds)
    else:
        seconds = str(seconds)
    current_time = str(hours) + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds
    var.set(current_time)
    root.after(500, updateTime(var))

time_display = StringVar()
updateTime(time_display)

ttk.Label(root, textvariable=time_display).grid(column=0, row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In following line, the code is calling `updateTime` directly; causing recursive call.

```
root.after(500, updateTime(var))
#                         ^   ^
```

---

Pass the function and argument without calling it will solve your problem.

```
root.after(500, updateTime, var)
```

Alternatively you can use `lambda`:

```
root.after(500, lambda: updateTime(var))
```

---

BTW, using [`time.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime), `updateTime` can be reduced:

```
def updateTime(var):
    var.set(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    root.after(500, updateTime, var)
```

Comment: OH MY GOD THAT'S SO OBVIOUS. I am new to tkinter, not at all to python or to programming. Such a dumb mistake! Thanks. Although I'm surprised it didn't error on receiving NoneType for an argument....would have been informative and then I would have seen the mistake immediately.

Comment: @Aerovistae, According to [`after` documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method), `None` is also a valid argument. (`None` is default value for `callback` parameter)